# Was Lilliard's shot in 2014 Game 6 against the Rockets released in time?

Tags: basketball, nba

In the game 6 of 2014 playoff series between the Trail Blazers and the Rockets, Damian Lilliard took an inbounds pass with 0.9s remaining and took what turned out to be the game-winning shot. Was his shot released before the buzzer, or should it have been a Houston win?

Answer (score 3):

The shot was in time. You can find it on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mejFtEY5faU) and you can hear and see (the clock) that the shot was taken *before* the buzzer went off.

[image]

Note: The time resumes with the catch, because the international Basketball [rules](http://www.fiba.basketball/OBR2017/yellowblue/Final.pdf) or NBA [rules](https://www.nba.com/media/dleague/1314-nba-rule-book.pdf) say so.

> **Art. 49 Timer: Duties** (FIBA)
>
> Starting the game clock when:
>
> (...)
>
> - During a throw-in, the ball touches or  is legally touched by a player on the  playing court.

---

> **Section VIII: Duties of Timers** (NBA)
>
> c.  If the game clock has been stopped and the ball is put in play by
>   a throw-in, the game clock and the 24-second clock shall be started
>   when  the ball is legally touched by any player on the court. The
>   starting of the game clock and the 24-second clock will be under the
>   control of the official timer.